# Pynamodb:it's possible to Pynamodb model with django REST framework

Tags: python, django

I want to use Pynamodb to drive dynamoDB with django REST framework.

I would like to know if Pynamodb model compatible with django REST ORM.

bets regards,

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not compatible. You can't create model serializers directly from PynamoDB models, but you can write a custom one extending from serializers.Serializer

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/